# Include header http " Pragma " when open a page

Tags: php, html, header, pragma

i have an issue. i have this piece of code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="https://testsp.eu/sites/SC1/0a18c942-c443-4d91-954b-e6a2bf6b6061/_layouts/15/listform.aspx">
      <input type="hidden" name="PageType" value="4" />
      <input type="hidden" name="ListId" value="&#123;F783213B&#45;D85D&#45;4580&#45;A48D&#45;3B7650F39970&#125;" />
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="429x07ec&lt;script&gt;alert&#40;1&#41;&lt;&#47;script&gt;c6lv0" />
      <input type="hidden" name="ContentTypeID" value="0x0101009780EDAE3CDE424E865934F078F59B4E00B67EBEA1D4DD80439046916AAD0BBD4C" />
      <input type="hidden" name="Source" value="https&#58;&#47;&#47;testsp&#46;reply&#46;eu&#47;sites&#47;SC1&#47;0a18c942&#45;c443&#45;4d91&#45;954b&#45;e6a2bf6b6061&#47;Attachments&#47;Forms&#47;AllItems&#46;aspx&#63;RootFolder&#61;Attachments&#37;2Ftesting&#37;2Dvia&#37;2Dvpn&#37;2Dopen&#37;2Dedit&#37;2Dand&#37;2Dsave&#37;2Dfiles&#37;2Don&#37;2Dtaamy&#37;2Dnew&#37;2Dfeature" />
      <input type="hidden" name="RootFolder" value="Attachments&#47;testing&#45;via&#45;vpn&#45;open&#45;edit&#45;and&#45;save&#45;files&#45;on&#45;tammy&#45;new&#45;feature" />
      <input type="hidden" name="AjaxDelta" value="1" />
      <input type="hidden" name="isStartPlt1" value="1455724318260" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit request" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

for make it work i have the use the following header http:

```
Pragma: SharePointAjaxDelta=|SITES|SC1|0A18C942-C443-4D91-954B-E6A2BF6B6261:|SITES|SC1|_CATALOGS|MASTERPAGE|TT.MASTER:1.15.0.0.0.15.0.4763.1000.2.FALSE.:en-US:en-US:RW');
```

Anyone have an idea how i can request that html page with the header "pragma"?

Thanks in advance